# How can I round a float to a given decimal precision

Tags: c, linux, floating-point, rounding

I need to convert a floating-point number with system precision to one with a specified precision (e.g. 3 decimal places) for the printed output. The fprintf function will not suffice for this as it will not correctly round some numbers. All the other solutions I've tried fail in that they all reintroduce undesired precision when I convert back to a float. For example:

```
float xf_round1_f(float input, int prec) {

    printf("%f\t",input);
    int trunc = round(input * pow(10, prec));
    printf("%f\t",(float)trunc);
    input=(float)trunc / pow(10, prec);
    printf("%f\n",input);
    return (input);

}
```

This function prints the input, the truncated integer and the output to each line, and the result looks like this for some numbers supposed to be truncated to 3 decimal places:

49.975002   49975.000000    49.974998

49.980000   49980.000000    49.980000

49.985001   49985.000000    49.985001

49.990002   49990.000000    49.990002

49.995003   49995.000000    49.994999

50.000000   50000.000000    50.000000

You can see that the second step works as intended - even when "trunc" is cast to float for printing - but as soon as I convert it back to a float the precision returns. The 1st and 6th rows illustrate problem cases.

Surely there must be a way of resolving this - even if the 1st row result remained 49.975002 a formatted print would give the desired effect, but in this case there is a real problem.

Any solutions?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: This is unavoidable with binary floating point, sorry.

Comment: @Eric Sorry deleted it as soon as posted since it also didn't answer the question :-).

Comment: Usually the approach in such cases -- often for example for currency amounts, is to use an integer type and convert it to fixed precision for display purposes. E.g. for currency you might use int32_t cents. Some programming languages (e.g. COBOL) have specific types to deal with this issue. The fundamental problem is that 5 does not go into 2 in much the same way that 3 does not go into 10, so any decimal number is an infinitely recurring expansion in binary.

Comment: @JWDN: Your question was likely voted down because you still have not specified the problem precisely, you are not using floating-point correctly, and you probably should not be using it. There are alternative ways to do arithmetic if you want to preserve decimal digits. Floating point was designed for mathematical, scientific, and engineering calculations, with large dynamic range and good mathematical properties for those purposes. You are using it for a different purpose than it was designed for, so of course you are having problems. The answer you accepted is a kludge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** it appears you may only care about the printed results. `printf` is generally smart enough to do proper rounding to the number of digits you specify. If you give a format of `"%.3f"` you will probably get what you need.

---

If your only problem is with the cases that are *below* the desired number, you can easily fix it by making everything higher than the desired number instead. Unfortunately this increases the absolute error of the answer; even a result that was exact before, such as `50.000` is now off.

Simply add this line to the end of the function:

```
input=nextafterf(input, input*1.0001);
```

See it in action at http://ideone.com/iHNTzs

```
49.975002   49975.000000    49.974998   49.975002
49.980000   49980.000000    49.980000   49.980003
49.985001   49985.000000    49.985001   49.985004
49.990002   49990.000000    49.990002   49.990005
49.995003   49995.000000    49.994999   49.995003
50.000000   50000.000000    50.000000   50.000004
```

Comment: I'd like to say thank you, first for revealing that my long-held assumption that printf ALWAYS truncated numbers appears to incorrect - is this platform-dependent?. Second, even if printf DID behave the way I had assumed, this solution would solve the problem.

Comment: @JWDN, I don't know if it's platform-dependent or not, but it works that way for the platforms *I* use.

Comment: [correction] printf on it's own is in fact unreliable, as I suspected - eg printf("%.2f\n",7.895f) - however your main solution seems to work nicely for positive numbers. I suppose that for negatives the syntax should be input=nextafterf(input, input-1.0).

Comment: @JWDN, if `7.895f` actually becomes `7.89499999` then it's not going to round to two decimal places the way you expect. To fix my formula for both positive and negative numbers, use `nextafterf(input, 1.1*input)`.

Comment: @JWDN re platform-dependent printf: you might find my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/ a good read.

Comment: Another drawback of `nextafterf(input, input+1.0)` is that it may produce unexpected results for values of `input` such that `input == input+1.0`. `copysignf(FLT_MAX, input)` is a better second argument to  `nextafterf()`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, very good point. I've modified my answer, although your suggestion might be even better.

Comment: Happy to say I have now implemented the nextafter() function using FLT_MAX and it seems to reliably behave as expected: I have used an "if" branch to determine the sign and used FLT_MAX or -FLT_MAX instead of calling copysign(), which I think is a bit faster. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Binary floating-point cannot represent most decimal numerals exactly. Each binary floating-point number is formed by multiplying an integer by a power of two. For the common implementation of `float`, IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point, that integer must be in (–2<sup>24</sup>, 2<sup>24</sup>). There is no integer *x* and integer *y* such that *x*•2<sup>*y*</sup> exactly equals 49.975. Therefore, when you divide 49975 by 1000, the result **must** be an approximation.

If you merely need to format a number for output, you can do this with the usual `fprintf` format specifiers. If you need to compute exactly with such numbers, you may be able to do it by scaling them to representable values and doing the arithmetic either in floating-point or in integer arithmetic, depending on your needs.

Comment: I do appreciate this, but surely I don't have to resort to converting each number to a string, evaluating each digit after the decimal and converting back into a number? I was hoping to avoid this (and I'm not even sure it would work).

Comment: @JWDN: You seem to have missed the point. You **cannot** convert back to a number (a `float`) and get 49.975 exactly. The method used to do the rounding is irrelevant. There is **no value** of a `float` that is exactly 49.975. No matter what bits you put into a `float`, it will never have exactly the value 49.975. The values in your examples that appear to be correct are illusions, other than 50; they appear that way only because you have printed a limit number of digits.

Comment: Honestly I DO understand this. But I'm not the first person to come up against this, and for many applications it is not acceptable - so I am still (perhaps vainly) hoping for a solution.

Comment: @JWDN: The solution is to not use a binary floating-point datatype.

Comment: @JWDN: You have not really stated your problem yet. If your problem is “I want 49.975 in a binary floating-point object”, the answer is you are not going to get it, because it is logically impossible. However, if you explain more about the larger computation you are trying to do, there may be solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, while I only need the output to be formatted to the correct precision, you can see that faced with a number like "49.974998" I still have a problem which cannot be solved by fprintf. I may make numerous calculations for which the result is 49.975, give or take 0.0001, but it is absolutely critical that in every case the printed output is 49.975, the correctly rounded result.

Comment: @JWDN: `fprintf(stdout, "%.3f", 49.974998f)` yields “49.975”. Why do you think `fprintf` cannot format this as you desire?

Comment: sadly this does not always work: eg. printf("%.2f\n",7.895f);

Comment: @JWDN: The problem there is not `printf`, it's that the closest representable value in binary floating-point is less than 7.895, hence it gets rounded down by `printf`.

Comment: @Oli, suppose 7.90 is the one of only a few acceptable outputs, and 7.89 would be rejected. If I feed my function 7.895 (an exact number) and it spits back 7.89, I don't particularly care that this is because of the inability of the system to represent a binary number to infinite precision! I really do appreciate your responses, but I need a solution to a real-world problem in C which doesn't require re-writing all my code to use integers instead. Happily, the solution suggested by Mark Ransom, above, neatly resolves the issue, when printf() is combined with nextafterf().

Comment: P.S. - I really would appreciate whoever marked down this question to reconsider - many people have posted to StackOverflow looking for an adequate solution to this problem, and this is the first time I've actually seen one.

Comment: @JWDN: But the answer you've accepted doesn't work in the general case.  On average, it makes things worse.

Comment: @Oli - Correct, in general, but not if you are trying to round a number from it's original precision! In any case where you would want to round a number from it's original precision, you are not typically concerned about the value of the lowest possible digit, which is the one affected by nextafterf(). Or put another way, rounding is all about intentional loss of precision - what we want to ensure is that when specific values are input, the rounded output is true to the original, not how the system decides to re-interpret the number in binary.

Comment: @Eric, I respectfully disagree. It only seems like a Kludge because the programming community has accepted that when you tell a computer "7.895" it's acceptable for the computer to treat it as 7.89499999.Using integers to perform calculations which are inherently floating-point is simply impractical when designing software which uses large libraries of functions not configured to operate on that basis. Therefore, I stand by description of the problem (how best to reduce the precision in a floating point number) and my ranking of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you require exact representation of all decimal fractions with three digits after the decimal point, you can work in thousandths. Use an integer data type to represent one thousand times the actual number for all intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed point numbers.  That is where you keep the actual numbers in a wide precision integer format, for example long or long long.  And you also keep the number of decimal places.  And then you will also need methods to scale the fixed point number by the decimal places.  And some way to convert to/from strings.

The reason why you are having trouble that 1/10 is not representable exactly as a fractional power of 2 (1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc).  This is the same reason that 1/3 is a repeating decimal in base 10 (0.33333...).